# How can I keep my first button from disappearing as a create a new one?

Tags: c#, picturebox

I'm trying to draw out pictureboxes during runtime as I can do right from the toolbox. That is, set the location at the mouselocation, resize it as I hold down the button and drag it across the form. All that I've accomplished in the code. But as I start the draw the second picturebox the first one disappears, I want to keep adding more pictureboxes to the form, if I remove the `MouseMove` event and move `PictureBox pb1 = new PictureBox();` down to the `MouseDown` event it lets me add more buttons, but then I can't resize them obviously.

```
    int cellSize = 10;
    int numOfCells = 500;

    PictureBox pb1 = new PictureBox();
    int Mx, My;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
    }

    public void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Point p = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
        Mx = p.X;
        My = p.Y;
        int xSnap = (Mx / cellSize) * cellSize;
        int ySnap = (My / cellSize) * cellSize;

        pb1.BackColor = (Color.Red);

        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            pb1.Size = new Size(xSnap - pb1.Left, ySnap - pb1.Top);
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Point p = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
        Mx = p.X;
        My = p.Y;
        int xSnap = (Mx / cellSize) * cellSize;
        int ySnap = (My / cellSize) * cellSize;

        pb1.Location = new Point(xSnap, ySnap);
        pictureBox1.Controls.Add(pb1);
    }
```

Comment: You need to add your `pb1 = new PictureBox();` code into MouseDown event. In MouseMove you have to find which picture box is being resized. Otherwise you'll end up resizing last picture box assigned to pb1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're always re-using the same `PictureBox` instance.

You need to create a new instance every time you want to add a new one, by writing `new PictureBox()`.